# jquery last select selector value

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I've been trying to get my second select "selected" value, but it is allways returning me "". Actually i have selected the second option on the second select. It seems to keep returning me the first option and not actually the option that is selected.

This is the HTML displayed:

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="tableButtonsFilter">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="firstLineFilters">
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-glintt btn-circle btn-lg" id="1" name="buttonFilterResultsCabecalho" disabled="">
                  <i class="icon fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-glintt btn-circle btn-lg" id="1" name="buttonFilterResultsCabecalho" disabled="">           <i class="icon fa fa-search"></i>           </button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-glintt btn-circle btn-lg" id="1" name="buttonFilterResultsCabecalho">           <i class="icon fa fa-search"></i>           </button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="secondLineFilters">
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="input-group"> 
                          <select class="form-control selectFilter" name="filterSelect">               
                            <option value=""></option><option value="1">SGICM</option>
                            <option value="2">HIS</option>             
                          </select> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="input-group"> 
                          <select class="form-control selectFilter" name="filterSelect">               
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="3">teste</option>             
                          </select> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this image you can notice that the second entry is selected:

[image: Selected Values]

I have already tried with:

```js
$("select[class='form-control selectFilter']:last option:selected").val();

$("select[class='form-control selectFilter']:last option:selected").attr('value');

$("[name='filterSelect']:last").val();
```

Allways getting "".

If i try:

```js
$("[name='filterSelect']").val();
```

It will return me "1" <- Expected value.

Can you help please?

**EDIT:**
When testing on chrome console with this HTML page and after selecting "SGICM" on the first select and "teste" on the second select, if i run:
$("[name='filterSelect']:last").val();

on the console, the output will be ""

**EDIT2:**
After some debugging and seeing that i was being able to get the right selected value in jsfiddle, concluded that after commenting some bootstrap and other template files used, selects were working properly. Will try to get to this later...

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: It's better to use `.form-control.selectFilter` to select classes, rather than using `[class=...]`.

Comment: why do You try to get :last?

Comment: Your first code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qdo5okvo/ When I select `teste` from the second menu, it returns `3`.

Comment: Why is `1` the expected value? The last menu is the one with `teste`, so the expected value is `3`.

Comment: @Barmar 1 is the expected value to the first select, not the second seelct

Comment: But `:last` means you want the second select.

Comment: You understand that `:last` means the last one in the DOM, not the last one that the user clicked on, right?

Comment: @Barmar Right :) That's exactly what i want. To explain you, i am constructing, placing selects dinamically on page as user selects (it's a tree structure). The second select entries are built after user takes an action on the first select. Will try to publish a zip with the html code of the page and jquery/bootstrap. I already tested on chrome console, once again and is actually returning ""

Comment: What's exactly what you want? The last in the DOM or the last one the user clicked on?

Comment: @Barmar Last one in the DOM

Comment: Please put relevant HTML into the question, and not on some external file hoster for download.

Comment: Ok... took out all bootstrap references out and tested and seems to be working... Something is not working as expected here -.-' Thanks. I'll try to understand what is messing this up.

Answer (score 0):

`$("select[class='form-control selectFilter']:last option:selected").val()`
 statement will return defined value, only if you have made selection of option in the last `<select>` (of relevant classes) element in DOM.
Following code works:

```
$("select").change(function(){
   alert ($(this).val())
});
```

If you want to realize a tree, I think you need either assign unique id for every `select` or add specific class name for the only last changed `select`

```
$("select[class='form-control selectFilter']").change(function(){
   $("select").removeClass("active_sel");
   $(this).addClass("active_sel");
   alert ($(this).val())
});
```

and after that you can use current select value:

```
$("select[class*='active_sel']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector:

```
$('option:nth-of-type(2)').eq(1)
```

and to get the value, you can use:

```
$('option:nth-of-type(2)').eq(1).attr('value')
```

---

**Explanation:**

You want the value of the second `option` of the second `select`.

The selector `option:nth-of-type(2)` means *the second option*.

The selector `option:nth-of-type(2).eq(1)` means *the second option, the second time*.

Comment: But if try $("[name='filterSelect']").val(); in jsfiddle it actually works.

Comment: Ok, understood what's your point, but it is getting fixed value of the select, even if i select another value inside of it

Comment: Not to worry. I see now that I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually worked around this and asociated an on change event to record the user selection on a global variable as I was not being able to get the select:last .

```js
$(document).on("change","[name='filterSelect']",function(){
 alert($(this).val());
})
```